# Checking a radiobutton if a specific activity is chosen

Tags: java, android, radio-button, oncreate

In my code, when an activity is opened/started, I am trying to check off one of the radiobuttons in the menu. I have a function in the onCreate method, but I am getting an error saying "int cannot be dereferenced." How do I fix it in this context? Or, is there a completely different way to go about my goal that would work?

onCreate method

```
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_markets);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    R.id.servemenu.setChecked(true);  //this what what I am using to check the radio button

    //home button

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMarkets.this, ActivityMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //Don't know what this is for but I'm not gonna mess with it

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    //Menu I think

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

.xml menu code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/servemenu"
        android:title="Markets We Serve" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/federalmenu"
        android:title="Federal" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/statelocalmenu"
        android:title="State and Local" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/commercialmenu"
        android:title="Commercial" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly reference the button the way you are doing it.

`R.id.servemenu` is just an integer which identifies the radiobutton within the view. You must retrieve the radiobutton by using `R.id.servemenu`, if that is indeed the ID of your RadioButton.

You should do it like this,

`RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.servemenu);
 rb.setChecked(true);`

Comment: Thank you! Is there an import package for RadioButton? When the code compiles I'm getting the error: "cannot find symbol class RadioButton"

Comment: I believe it is `import android.widget.RadioButton`

Comment: That worked :)
however, now I'm getting a NPE.Do you have any idea why calling setChecked() on rb would be considered a null object reference?

Comment: If you are getting a NPE when calling the `setChecked`, it means the RadioButton is null. is the ID of your RadioButton in your xml layout `servemenu`?

Comment: How would I fix that? (sorry about all these questions, I'm fairly new to java)

Comment: Im guessing you didn't give your RadioButton an ID in the xml layout. For it to work, it needs to be `R.id.(ID of radio button)` without parenthesis.

Comment: Because it's in a menu, isn't that automatically associated if I give the item an id? (I added the menu xml code above)

Comment: Ah, it was not clear that you were using a group instead of an actual radio button. Google how to set a group item checked in android and I think you'll find your answer.